# Drop down state list

Tags: links

In preview for my petition, the drop down state list is showing options, but when I go to the actual petition the state list says "non found"
I think a bug?
CiviCRM 5.3.0

Comment: can  you provide more details please like screeshot etc. Also can you try to replicate this on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: Works on sandbox and worked before upgrade. Cannot add image, but in preview get drop down of states, in signing, get message in state box 'none found' when enter address. Aus is selected as country for petitions